# XSLT - add new node to given position

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml like following xml,

```
<doc>
<footnote>
    <p type="Foot">
        <link ref="http://www.facebook.com"/>
        <c>content</c>
        <d>cnotent</d>
    </p>
    <p type="Foot">
        <link ref="http://www.google.com"/>
        <c>content</c>
        <d>cnotent</d>
    </p>
</footnote>
</doc>
```

My requirmets are,

1) add dynamic id to `<p>` node which has attribute `type="Foot"`

2) add new node named `<newNode>` inside `<p>` node

3) add dynamic id to <`newNode>`

so output sholud be

```
<doc>
<footnote>
    <p id="ref-1" type="Foot">
        <newNode type="direct" refId="foot-1"/>
        <link ref="http://www.facebook.com"/>
        <c>content</c>
        <d>cntent</d>
    </p>
    <p id="ref-2" type="Foot">
        <newNode type="direct" refId="foot-2"/>
        <link ref="http://www.google.com"/>
        <c>content</c>
        <d>cotent</d>
    </p>
</footnote>
</doc>
```

I wrote following xsl to do that

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- add new dynamic attribute to <p> -->
    <xsl:template match="p[@type='Foot']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="'ref-'"/> 
                <xsl:number count="p[@type='Foot']" level="any"/>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />

            <!-- add new node with dynamic attribute -->
            <newNode type="direct">
                <xsl:attribute name="refId">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'foot-'"/>
                    <xsl:number count="p[@type='Foot']" level="any"></xsl:number>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </newNode>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>
```

My problem is it add new node ad last node inside `<p>` node (as show below) which I need to add as first node inside `<p>` node

```
      <p id="ref-1" type="Foot">
            <link ref="http://www.facebook.com"/>
            <c>content</c>
            <d>cntent</d>
            <newNode type="direct" refId="foot-1"/>
        </p>
```

How can I place  as first node inside `<p>` node as shown below?

```
    <p id="ref-1" type="Foot">
        <newNode type="direct" refId="foot-1"/>
        <link ref="http://www.facebook.com"/>
        <c>content</c>
        <d>cntent</d>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you copy the child elements after creating the new node:

```
<xsl:template match="p[@type='Foot']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="'ref-'"/> 
            <xsl:number count="p[@type='Foot']" level="any"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

        <!-- add new node with dynamic attribute -->
        <newNode type="direct">
            <xsl:attribute name="refId">
                <xsl:value-of select="'foot-'"/>
                <xsl:number count="p[@type='Foot']" level="any"></xsl:number>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </newNode>

        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>
```